# How to find AlarmManager service holding partial wakelock on behalf of which app

Tags: android, android-wake-lock

I can observe my device is not going to sleep because alarm is holding a partial wakelock, but i don't know how to find app on behalf of which alarm is holding wakelock.

Answer (score 1):

AlarmManager provides access to the system alarm services. These allow you to schedule an application to be run at some point in the future. When an alarm goes off, the Intent that has been registered for it is broadcasted by the system, automatically starting the target application if it is not already running. Registered alarms are retained while the device is asleep (and can optionally wake the device up if they go off during that time), but will be cleared if it is turned off and rebooted. The Alarm Manager holds a CPU wake lock as long as the alarm receiver's onReceive() method is executing. This guarantees that the phone will not sleep until you have finished handling the broadcast. Once onReceive() returns, the Alarm Manager releases this wake lock. This means that the phone will in some cases sleep as soon as your onReceive() method completes. more Detail

https://github.com/asksven/BetterBatteryStats-Knowledge-Base/wiki/AlarmManager

Answer (score 0):

You can also look at [battery-historian](https://github.com/google/battery-historian). It's a very helpful tool for finding unreleased wakelocks and logging battery history.